# Writing Questions and answers to a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to setup and write a question and its corresponding answers to a table view with each cell representing one of the answers from a dictionary and a question.

The dictionary is setup as follows:

```
struct Quest {
   question: String,
   ans1: String,
   ans2: String,
   ans3: String,
   ans4: String,
   cor: String
}
```

The struct can hold anywhere from 1 questions [0] through [100]

I was attempting to call the reloadata() function but that loads up a different question in each cell, whereas I need to load the question first and then the four answers.  Just not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is my cellFor code:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        let myView = cell.viewWithTag(3)
        let myItem = items[indexPath.row]
        print(indexPath.row)
        label1?.text = "Question"
        
        return cell
```

I tried having it return the cell and then added the code below that to load the next one but it keeps telling me that once I return the rest of the code won't execute, which I understand.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I was attempting to call the reloadata() function but that loads up a different question in each cell, whereas I need to load the question first and then the four answers."

Wait, what? you want just the question to appear in a cell? Do you want the question in a cell and then 4 "child cells" that you can expand? That sounds like a sectioned table view.

Comment: 1 Cell holds the question, which is disabled so it won't fire the didselect call, then four cells that hold the four answers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a sectioned table view, with each section containing the question in the section header in the cells in that section containing the answers.